# Fail2Ban: Service failed when log files symlink to another device

Tags: symlink, fail2ban

I am using a Raspberry Pi. To reduce I/O on my SD-Card I symlink all important log files to an external USB-mounted Harddrive.

**Example:**

```
ln -s /media/usb-device/logs/auth.log /var/log/auth.log
```

The logging works fine. But fail2ban seems not to like that. When I enable my ssh-monitoring in my `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` file,

```
# [sshd]
enabled = true
bantime = 3600
```

fail2ban crash during executing this command `systemctl restart fail2ban.service`

I have tried to hardcode the path:

```
# logpath = %(sshd_log)s
logpath = /media/usb-devive/logs/auth.log
```

But fail2ban throws the same error:

```
fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-04-28 20:42:33 CEST; 45s ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 3014 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3045 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 658 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Apr 28 20:42:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 28 20:42:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
Apr 28 20:42:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 28 20:42:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Apr 28 20:42:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 28 20:42:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"devive" in the `logpath` is spelt incorrectly

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.